# How to Create v4 Bitly Short link using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, bit.ly

We want to migrate v3 to v4 bitly using javascript.
We were using below code in v3 bitly:

```
var x = "";
$.bitlr({
    apiKey: '......',
    link: longurl,
    anchor: false,
    success: function (newLink) {
        x = newLink;
    }
});
return x;
```

Comment: https://support.bitly.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004395631-Migrating-from-v3-to-v4-of-the-Bitly-API